# Solving specific system of equations with inequalities

Tags: inequality, systems-of-equations

I am coding something in Ruby and I came across this math problem.
I have a system of equations and inequalities that looks like this:

$$
a = \sum \frac{a_n * x_n}{100}\\
b = \sum \frac{b_n * x_n}{100}\\
c = \sum \frac{c_n * x_n}{100}
$$

And for every $x_n$ I have:

$$
\text{min}x_n < x_n < \text{max}x_n
$$

There can be random numbers of $x$ and these equations. But let's say that it won't be larger than $10$:

$$
n \leq 10
$$

I know all values, but $x_n$.
Is there a way of calculating each $x_n$? Or at least get a narrower range for them?

Comment: Given the information provided, it's not possible to uniquely determine the values of $x_n$.

Comment: Ok thank you. Can we at least somehow lower the number of possible values for each xn? Anything that could help my script "guess" those ideal values..

Comment: Since you know the values of $\text{min}x_n$ and $\text{max}x_n$ for each $n$, you already have a range for each $x_n$. You also know the value of $c$, so we can use this information to help narrow down the possible range for each $x_n$.

Comment: Yes, but even with this knowledge and when I make the set of xn values smaller by setting the step of these values to 5 (so xn can be any of: [5,10,15,..]), the number of possible combinations can still be as high as millions. So I am just curious if I can do anything from a math standpoint to help the script find those values.

Comment: I am not certain, whether it would be possible, you rather would need optimization techniques to minimize/maximize a particular objective function, here.